# ifstream_iterator and ifstream

Tags: c++

The task is to read numbers from file to vector. Format is: one number per line. I want to make with STL-style. So, I wrote such code:

```
::std::deque<size_t> Input(const ::std::string& filename) {
    ::std::deque<size_t> result;
    try {
        ::std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ::std::ios::binary);
        file.exceptions(::std::ifstream::failbit |
                       ::std::ifstream::badbit);

        ::std::copy(::std::istreambuf_iterator<size_t>(file),
                    ::std::istreambuf_iterator<size_t>(),
                    ::std::back_inserter(result));

    } catch ( ::std::exception& e ) {
        ::std::cout << e.what() << ::std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works fine, and I get what I want (all numbers from the file), but also I get an exception with failbit at end of file. What's the problem? I don't want to use getline() and parse by hand -- wanna ask STL do it for me.
UPDATE: I checked -- there is no new line at the end of file.

Comment: Failbit and eofbit both getting set is expected.

Comment: Because that's what it's supposed to do. Pretty much any time eofbit gets set, failbit gets set too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>**TL;DR:**  If the stream run out of content while trying to read a new value, `failbit` is set.</sup>

---

It's defined in the standard that using a `istream_iterator` has the same effect as doing:

```
*in_stream >> value; /* istream_iterator::operator++ */
return        value; /* istream_iterator::operator*  */
```

---

Which in the case with handling integers (such as `size_t`) will results in calls to the below (can be read about under *27.6.1.2.2/2 - lib.istream.formatted.arithmetic*).

```
use_facet<numget> (loc).get (*this, 0, *this, err, lval)

...

setstate (err);
```

---

`err` is passed by reference and will be set to whatever errors the function might run into. Below is a snippet from the standards definition of `use_facet<numget> (loc).get`:

> **22.2.2.1.2**/8 `-` [*lib.facet.num.get.virtuals*]
>
> The `in` iterator is always left pointing one position beyond the last
>   character successfully matched. If `val` is set, then `err` is set to
>   `str.goodbit;` or to `str.eofbit` if, when seeking another character to
>   match, it is found that `(in == end)`.
>
> If `val` is not set, then `err` is
>   set to `str.failbit`; or to `(str.failbit|str.eofbit)` if the reason for
>   the failure was that `(in == end)`.

---

<sup>**TL;DR:**  If the stream run out of content while trying to read a new value, `failbit` is set.</sup>